# How does SHA-3 work with mappings in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'm having some trouble understanding how `mapping` works in Solidity. As it was explained to me, the value passed into the `mapping` is hashed using SHA-3. Once it's hashed, the new hashed value is used as the location of where in memory the value is stored. I'm confused because I don't understand why SHA-3 is producing a real location in memory. Doesn't SHA-3 produce random values of a fixed length? How could the hashed value possibly be used to tell the computer where a value is in memory if SHA-3 is supposed to produce arbitrary values? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> *the value passed into the `mapping` is hashed using SHA-3.*

The **value** is not hashed. However - the **storage slot location** is determined by a **hash** of the property position within the contract and few other factors, such as index and datatype of the key.

See the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) for specifics. You might be interested in the section starting

> *The value corresponding to a mapping key `k` is located at `keccak256(h(k) . p)`*